# git and visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I try to update my information under git settings in Visual Studio 2013, I get the following error:

```
 An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. 
 Category = Config (Error).
 Multivar incompatible with simple set
```

There are others who have problems with libgit2, but not related to config. Any ideas?

/ Erik

Comment: I would add the visual-studio and the visual-studio-version tags, Is it for 2012 or 2013? If you found the answer through other means, you can post it on stackoverflow as an answer.

Comment: Didn't you solve with my answer?
If so, please accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same error but with Visual Studio **2015**. I used `git bash` with this command:

```
git config --global -l
```

which showed me I had 2 `user.email` addresses set. That is likely the meaning of "multivar". After that, I entered:

```
git config --global -e
```

which opened an editor, from whom I could remove the unwanted (duplicated in my case) line. No more errors in Visual Studio.
If you don't have `git bash`, simply edit the file `~/.gitconfig` file.

I'm into the Linux world, so I feel much more comfortable with `bash`, that also offers more options.